# How can app be read only for user and only admin have permission to post (using firestorm data server)

Tags: android, ios

I want to make an iOS and Android app using firestorm as data server, but I only want my user to be able to read the content like a news feed, and me as the admin would be the only one with permission to post, should I Make 2 UI Views (1 for user, 1 for admin) or do I just make the app rules as read only and upload post from firebase itself?

Comment: Based upon who logs in the app. You should have home screen different for admin and viewers . Basically you should provide acccess controls to users and for admin , you should allow posting . two views or one view depends upon how complex and different are your screens. If it s just a text fields. You can just hide it for viewers and enable it for admin

Answer (score -2):

I would make the app read from the data source and not have any editing ability.

You could have your own admin app to post content, or you could use something like a web app to post content.

Don't use 2 views in the same app.

Comment: How would I have my own admin app to post content? You mean that I should create an app for users and one for admin?

Comment: That was what I meant.  If you try to hide the admin screen in the normal app, it might be that a user would discover it.